# how to support styling of android library activity views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-library

I am giving an activity inside a library and I want to give a provision to change the UI styles, say a button bacground color(with selecter). How to achive this? I don't want to expose my xml files to the user.

Comment: provide getter and setter for you view and there properties and expose to user

Comment: Styleable is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to archive this is here:
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Example:

```
public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.PieChart,
        0, 0); 

   try { 
       mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PieChart_showText, false);
       mTextPos = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PieChart_labelPosition, 0);
   } finally { 
       a.recycle();
   } 
}
```

In your Resources: (res/values/attrs.xml)

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And finally you can call:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews">
 <com.example.customviews.charting.PieChart
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```